# Run a shell script on PC shutdown while network is still up or set delay in network to execute script in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, sh, systemctl

I am trying to run a script for git auto push when we shut down the PC. But my script and service file only execute the commit command and after that, the network goes down. So, it does not execute the push command.

How can I complete the execution of the script before the network goes down?

My service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=It will auto commit and push using auto-commit-push-script
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Before=halt.target poweroff.target  shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
# RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/user/git-auto-commit/git_auto_commit.sh
TimeoutStopSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target poweroff.target shutdown.target
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/Basics
username="xyz"
password="xyz"
git add .
git commit -m "Auto-Commit On PC shut down"
git push https://$username:$password@github.com/username/Basics.git --all
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this issue?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Git - *any* network operation would have the same issue, e.g., scp, rsync, `tar cf - dir | ssh backupsite savestuff`, and so on. VonC's answer is a good one, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after that, the network goes down

Actually, the network might very well be down *before* your service starts any Git command.

Check first if adding to your service definition `After=networking.service` would help.
[From here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294054/7490):

> `After=` not only declares that your service is started by the networking service, it also is declaring that the services should be stopped in the inverse order-- *before* networking is shut down.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. let me try this one.

Comment: Still, there is the same issue. It is working 3 out of 4 times. 1 time it is still not pushing the code.

Comment: @NeelGajjar Try and put your `foo.conf` in `/lib/systemd/system/foo.d`: those in `/lib` should stop first, while other services are still active.

Comment: I am not getting your point. Can you please elaborate in some more detail?

Comment: @NeelGajjar From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html: "In addition to /etc/systemd/system, the drop-in ".d/" directories for system services can be placed in /usr/lib/systemd/system or /run/systemd/system directories. Drop-in files in /etc/ take precedence over those in /run/ which in turn take precedence over those in /usr/lib/. " The idea is to put a `/usr/lib/system/foo.d/foo.conf` in the folder with the least precedence, meaning: it should be the first to stop, *before* the others (including network)